# Probability of getting within $k$ heads of $50$

Tags: probability, solution-verification, central-limit-theorem

You flip a coin $100$ times. What's the probability that you get between $[50 - k, 50 + k]$ heads for some integer $k$? I know we can use the CLT with mean $50$ and standard deviation $5$, and I end up finding:

$$P(X \leq 50 + k) - P(X \leq 50 - k) = P(Z \leq k/5) - P(Z \leq -k/5) = \Phi(k/5) - \Phi(-k/5) = \Phi(k/5) - (1 - \Phi(k/5)), $$

which simplifies to $2\cdot \Phi(k/5) - 1$, which is clearly less than $1$. Can someone please point out what I did wrong?

Comment: Why do you think your answer is wrong?  Your answer should be between zero and 1.

Comment: I was thinking of the case when $2 \cdot \Phi(k/5)$ is really small so that subtracting $1$ makes it negative

Comment: $\Phi(0) = \frac 12, k>0$ so $\Phi(k/5) > \frac 12$

Comment: @fda For $k=0$ you see that your term is not very precise: $P(X=50)≈2Φ(0/5)−1=0.00\%$, although $P(X=50)=7.96\%$ Anyway, a reply would be kindful.

Comment: @fda Any (further) questions?

Comment: No, thank you! @callculus

Comment: @fda OK. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The random variable for the number of heads ($x$) is binomial distributed like $X\sim\textrm{Bin}\left(100,\frac12\right)$. That means that X is a discrete random variable. Thus $P(50-k\leq X \leq 50+k)=P(X\leq 50+k)-P(X\leq 49-k)$. Now you have two options. Applying central limit theorem with continuity correction factor $(b)$ or without it $(a)$.

$(a) \ $  $P(50-k\leq X \leq 50+k)\approx \Phi\left(\frac{50+k-50}{5}\right)-\Phi\left(\frac{49+k-50}{5}\right)=\Phi\left(\frac{k}{5}\right)-\Phi\left(\frac{k-1}{5}\right)$

$(b) \ $$P(50-k\leq X \leq 50+k)\approx \Phi\left(\frac{50+0.5+k-50}{5}\right)-\Phi\left(\frac{49+0.5+k-50}{5}\right)=\Phi\left(\frac{k+0.5}{5}\right)-\Phi\left(\frac{k-0.5}{5}\right)$